# How should my URL encoding look if I enter it manually?

Tags: java, post, https, url-encoding

I want to "fill in" a form on a website from java. I used charles proxy to determine that pressing the "Register" button on this form sends a URL encoded Http post request.

For example, if the website were:

https://apps.business.com/register

Then the http post was sent to:

https://apps.business.com/registersend

I then used the Advanced Rest Client plug-in for chrome to send a sample registration request successfully.

However, I now want to manually send this request from Java. I thought that as it was URL encoding, it would be a simple case of appending a URL encoded string to the rest of the URL. Something like:

https://apps.business.com/registersend/?email=me%40hotmail.com

etc., but I can't seem to get this to work and assume I'm missing something.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: POSt data is not sent via the URL. That'd be a GET query... which CAN be sent along with a POST request, but they're otherwise two completely separate mechanisms which can happen to share the same request.

Comment: Ok, so does this mean that when I'm inputting a URL encoded string into the post payload it's actually being passed as the contents of the post, rather than being appended to the URL? Sorry, seems a bit of a stupid question but the whole "URL encoding" part has got me confused. Thanks for the response.

Comment: POST data goes in the body of the request. GET data goes in the headers as part of the URL. basically the post data would look almost the same as the GET data, but their locations are totally different.

Answer (score 0):

To send HTTP POST you will need something like the HTTP Client API.

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/